# Android доступ к экземплярам класса

Tags: java, android

Имеется некоторый класс, например

```
public class People{
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public People(int id, String name){
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
    }
}
```

В различных частях приложения (Activity или Fragment) создаются экземпляры класса

Нужно, чтобы из определенной части приложения я мог получить доступ к списку экземпляров класса.

Да их можно передавать с помощью Bundle, но пользователь может не сразу перейти к странице, где этот список необходим. Как можно это реализовать?

**Upd:**

```
public class ObjectBasket {
private static ObjectBasket objectBasket;
private ArrayList<Object> objects;

public ObjectBasket(){
    objects = new ArrayList<>();
}

public ArrayList<Object> getObjects(){
    return objects;
}

public void addObject(Object object){
    objects.add(object);
}
```

}

Comment: Вам "лаба", про которую я говорил подходит или вы хотите послушать другие мнения?)

Comment: Ну да на самом деле, по другому особо никак

Comment: @Jarvis_J что нужно в конструкторе писать?(this.ctx = ctx? Просто мне нужно сохранять добавляемый любой класс, поэтому я указал Object

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от ваших задач и от того, добавляются ли объекты динамически или заданы сразу. Теоретически, если вы будете добавлять объекты "по ходу пьесы", даже контекст в конструктор передавать не надо.

Одна вещь в конструкторе понадобится точно `objects = new ArrayList<>();`.

`this.ctx = ctx;` делать нельзя. Так как в статических переменных это сразу утечка памяти. Лучше передавать его в функции, если он там вам потребуется.

Также необходимо добавить следующую переменную и метод:

```
private static ObjectBasket objectBasket;
public static ObjectBasket get(Context ctx){
    if (objectBasket == null) objectBasket = new ObjectBasket(Context ctx);
    return objectBasket;
}
```

Далее, вариант №1, элементы заданы сразу:

```
public ObjectBasket(Context ctx){
    objects = new ArrayList<>();
    Resources res = ctx.getResources();
    String names = res.getStringArray(R.array.names);

    for (int i=0;i<names.lenght;i++){
        People people = new People();
        people.setName(names[i]);
        ...// наполнение другими данными, например, из массивов
        objects.add(people);
    }   
}
```

Вариант №2, динамическое добавление:

```
public ObjectBasket(){
    objects = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void addPeople(String name && другие параметры||People people) {
    objects.add(people);
    //или
    People people = new People();
    people.setName(name);
    ...// наполнение другими данными
    objects.add(people);        
}
```

Получать:

```
public Object getObject(int position) {
    if (position>=objects.size()) return null; //или new People(-1,"Ноунэйм");
    return objects.get(position);
}
```

Вызывать из любого места:

```
ObjectBasket.get(context).getObject(position);
```

В этом же классе можно хранить любые переменные, доступ к которым нужен из нескольких мест. Например: `boolean fullVersion`, `boolean soundOn`, `boolean gameState` и т.д. и вызывать/устанавливать их через `get` и `set` методы:

```
ObjectBasket.get(context).setFullVersion(true);
//или
if (ObjectBasket.get(context).isSoundOn()){...};
```

Если у вас несколько разнородных объектов, можно создать `ArrayList` и соответствующие методы для каждого из них. Это сэкономит память - с `Objects` она будет занята больше (постоянно приводить `Object` к нужным типам).

[Учебник](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxhbmRsZXNzb25zfGd4OjNjMjBlNzMwZDUwNmM2YWM), откуда взято.

А вообще, такой паттерн программирования называется MVC, погуглите если интересно.

Comment: т.е чтобы добавить объект в разных частях. Мне необходимо создавать новый экземпляр public ObjectBasket() и передавать туда с помощью addObject(smartphone) экземпляр другого класса, который я хочу использовать в другом месте
}

Comment: нет, просто вызывайте `ObjectBasket.get()` - это статический метод. Если `ObjectBasket` не создан - он его создаст с нуля, иначе - вернет тот, который уже есть (со всеми заданными переменными)

Comment: извините, не весь код написал)) посмотрите, дополнил статик методом

Comment: Есть адаптер, который принимает List<Object> (который экземпляры классов я передал). Как мне конвертнуть к определенному классу? final Product product = objects.get(position);

Comment: обычным приведением типов: `Product product = (Product) objects.get(position)`. Только с такой реализацией лучше сначала проверить `if (objects.get(position) instanceOf Product)`, либо сделать `try/catch`

Comment: Все понял, вот так добавлять ObjectBasket.get(getContext()).addObject();

Comment: Только ошибку кидает при установке адаптера recyclerview, хотя по длине понятно, что объект добавился https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/845774/recyclerview-adapter-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-null